# Creating new Section in onenote using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, onenote

Hi I have searched through the internet looking for examples of creating a new onenote section and I can't find the right example for me to understand. The closest I can get to is using `.OpenHierarchy` function but I'm still very new to it and I couldn't get the parameters right.

I'm currently working on an OCR marco for multiple PDF file. Everything is working fine till I realise that I'm creating huge waste files on my computer.

Here's the code I used to delete all the pages created in the section

Dim oneNote As OneNote14.Application

```
Dim secDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set secDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Dim secNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Set secNodes = secDoc.DocumentElement.getElementsByTagName("one:Section")

' Get the first section.
Dim secNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Set secNode = secNodes(0)

Dim sectionName As String
sectionName = secNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("name").Text
Dim sectionID As String
sectionID = secNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("ID").Text

oneNote.DeleteHierarchy (sectionID)
oneNote.OpenHierarchy
End Sub
```

Deletehierarchy function deletes the entire section away leaving no section behind but my OCR macro requires at least one section to work.

Thanks for reading and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

oneNote.OpenHierarchy in vba does not allow bracklet and thats the issue that is causing the error.

solution:

oneNote.OpenHierarchy fileName, "", "New Section 1", 3